# Office 365 Calendar Issue

Tags: outlook, microsoft-office-365, calendar

We have a user who migrated from Office 2007 to Office 2016 install a few monthss ago. We use Office 365.

It has been working fine for those couple months, until now. Now, when some users try to look at that persons calendar to schedule meetings, they now see the box with the slashes through it. "No information available".

We tried the tricks like getting rid of autofill, redoing profile and redoing the calendar permissions to no avail. Anyone have any thoughts?

Edit: Free/Busy is unavailable both on the desktop APP and OWA.

It seems that if you have ever created a meeting with this user, that it now shows "No information available".

Comment: The version of Office that is running on their desktop is a lot less important to this question than the version(s) of Exchange server(s) being used and/or whether any of the users involved have been migrated to Exchange Online. What's the server side look like?

Comment: It was server 2010 SP3 Rollup 15. 14.03.0319.002. We have been using Office 365 (Exchange Online) since March 2016.

Comment: So have all users been completely migrated to Exchange Online? The mailbox in question is definitely hosted in Exchange Online and isn't somehow accidentally in an on-prem server?

Comment: Yes, they are all migrated to Exchange Online.

Comment: If others can't see the calendar entries and the mailbox owner/user hasn't somehow denied other people access to their mailbox, then you could open an Office 365 support incident - which is included with your Office 365 subscription and it sounds like an Exchange Online issue.

Comment: That is one of the 3 roads I went down. Thanks

Comment: @ToddWilcox If a calendar has over 1000 items in it in Exchange Online it can do this. You have to archive old calendar items and it then works again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try to login this mailbox with owner credential. I suppose there's something wrong on this mailbox.

Also, move this mailbox to other database (Move-Mailbox without TargetDatabase in Exchange Online) if this issue only occurs on this individual mailbox.